# How to use C++ libraries in Objective C

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

HI,

I was wondering how can I use C++ libraries in Objective C ?? Do i need to convert it to Objective C++ or I can use them Directly??

I read few post which ask the similar question but they have libraries for specific thing like Networking, My libraries are for graphics.

Also how would I test that which function of the library is supported and which is not??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to call then from and use the C++ heders in an Objective C++ file but this is just and Objective C code file with a .mm extension that uses C++ syntax rather than C. the methods and functions (if functions are declare extern "C") can be called from Objective C. Any C++ classes can only be used in the Objective C++ files unless cast to void* pointers to be passed through the Objective C.

Xcode/ OSX developer tools will manage these differences automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C++ works exactly how you would hope it would -- you name the file with a `.mm`, and then commix code written in the two languages.  Including a precompiled C++ library works fine from a .mm file.

Answer (score -1):

Link the object code with your compiler.